# How to dynamically read value from excel sheet columns in Python

Tags: python, excel, xlrd

I am working on a project where I have read data from `excel sheet` and upload it to API. One problem here is that the data inside the sheet is not fix which means that, lets say an attribute `weight` was in column 5 but later it can move to column 7. Lets say below is the excel sheet:

```
Name    Age     Gender      Weight      Category
xyz     20      M           76          A
abc     21      M           72          A 
pqr     22      M           77          B
```

SO lets say Age is column1. But later in some other files, it can be at column 4. So I have to write a script which can accept dynamic column and accordingly extract their data and upload it to API.

Below is the JSON data which I have to upload:

```
{
    "full_name":
    "gender":
    "age":
    "total_weight":
    "category":
}
```

To do this, I initially thought while processing the excel sheet, I will first extract the headers (column names) so I would know at which column attribute is present. So for this I did:

```
import xlrd 

mop_workbook = xlrd.open_workbook(mo_file_path)
mop_sheet = mop_workbook.sheet_by_index(0)

attr_list = []
for i in range(mop_sheet.ncols):
    attr_dict = dict()
    attr_dict['attribute'] = mop_sheet.cell_value(0, i)
    attr_dict['col_no'] = i
    attr_list.append(attr_dict)
```

Now `attr_list` contains:

```
[
    {
      "attribute": "Name",
      "col_no": 0
    },

      "attribute": "Age",
      "col_no": 1
    },

      "attribute": "Gender",
      "col_no": 2
    },

      "attribute": "Weight",
      "col_no": 3
    },

      "attribute": "Category",
      "col_no": 4
    },

]
```

Now with above data, I know which attribute is at which column. So even in future, if attribute column changes, I would not worry as I have its new col_no in the above list of dict. After this I just had to use the attribute's col_no and this is where I am getting confused. Below is the code snippet of how I normally extract cell value:

```
for row in range(total_row):
    if row != 0:   # skipping the 0th row of headers
        data = dict()
        
        data['full_name'] = str(mop_sheet.cell_value(row, 0))
```

Now in the above code, instead of `0` in `str(mop_sheet.cell_value(row, 0))`, I have to apply the column no from the list of dict I have created but I am getting confused on how to use it. Can anyone please help. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Just use the dictionary with the column name as key and set the index like this:

```
column_index= dict()
for i in range(mop_sheet.ncols):
    key = str(mop_sheet.cell_value(0, i))
    column_index[key.lower()] = i
```

The key is lower case that's why the .lower()

Later use it like this:

```
for row in range(total_row):
    if row != 0:   # skipping the 0th row of headers
        data = dict()
        
        data['full_name'] = str(mop_sheet.cell_value(row, column_index['name']))
        data['gender'] = str(mop_sheet.cell_value(row, column_index['gender']))
        # ...
```